# How to immutably update a map in Javascript

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, immutability

I am using `Redux` for `React` and I am trying to change a state which contains a `Map` but I'm not sure how to do it correctly.

I'm trying to use the update patterns listed here (but they show examples for objects and arrays only):  https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns

I got a constant map like this:

```
const propertiesMap1 = new Map([
["TITLE1",
    {
        propertyValues: {
            myProperty1 : "myVal1",
            myProperty2 : "myVal2",
            myProperty3 : "myVal3",                                                            
        },
        isOpen: true
    }
],
....
```

There are 2 maps like these in an array: `const arr = [map1, map2]`

I'm trying to update a value in a specific map like this:

```
function updateValueInProperties(array, index, category, value) 
{

return array.map( (item, index) => 
{
    if(index !== action.index) 
    {
        return item;
    }


    // Otherwise, this is the one we want - return an updated value
    return {
        ...item,
        item.get(category): {

        }
    };    
});
```

}

but the above has compilation errors..

How exactly do I update the map immutably?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:

To create a »updated clone«: `new Map(oldMap).set('x', 'y')` or `new Map(oldMap).delete('x')`.

**TLDR**

The constructor of a map takes an iterable and a map is one. So for instance:

```
const 
  m1 = new Map().set('x1', 'y1').set('x2', 'y2'),
  m2 = new Map([...m1.entries()])
;

m1 === m2 // false;
m2.get('x1') // y1
```

So, to update a map in such a way that a new map is created you can, you can convert the old map to an array using `.entries()`, update this array and turn that back into a map.

```
//update a value
const updated = new Map([...m1.entries()].map(
  ([key, val]) => [
    key, 
    key == 'x1' ? `updated ${val}` : val 
  ]
));
```

or even shorter, Thanks to all the comments of @VLAZ

```
const clone = new Map(oldMap).set('x', 'y')
```

*SUMMARY*

To `flat copy` a map you can use `new Map(old)` and to create a modified clone, than all those `delete()`, `set()` or `clear()` methods of the new Map can be used. An intermediate array may offer more flexibility for filtering etc, but will come to some performance cost.

Comment: If you update the map and clone it, that still changes the old map. I'd probably go for clone -> update -> return the clone.

Comment: Also, why clone the map by doing `new Map(oldMap.entries())`? You should be able to do it even more simply with `new Map(oldMap)`. So a clone with update would be `clone = new Map(oldMap).set("key", newValue);`

Comment: thanks again! I just started with the mind that modifying the array in between works…

Comment: Yeah, modifying the array would work but I think the Map is just more convenient to work with, since you don't need to iterate the whole array.

Comment: As I said, I just started of with that mind, your comments were really helpful and gave me a better direction. On the other hand, using an array in between may offer more flexibility, but that probably wont be needed for such a use case…

Comment: I think ultimately it doesn't matter. If you clone -> modify that is a bit more concise and lives up to the *spirit* of immutability even if it might break the letter of it. Upholding complete immutability would be to modify the array. Which has a bit more code. Still, an even better option is to have an immutable data structure that will do all that for you - `immutableMap.set(key, newValue)` will return a new copy but also do minimal changes and share its structure with the old copy of the map, so you don't get 2 copies of most values in memory.

Comment: Does the constructor of the map which receives an old map, makes a full deep copy of the old map?

Comment: no. a flat copy. Objects within a handed over by reference.